# Установочник

Tags: установка, delphi

Доброго времени суток.

Есть написанная отлаженная программа на Delphi с двумя БД, подключенными по ADO. Моя задача - сделать установочник, который устанавливал бы *.exe файл и эти две БД, создавал ярлык на раб. столе, а также закидывал все необходимые библиотеки.

Вопрос: какую утилиту для этого лучше использовать? Никаких наворотов не нужно. Нужна только быстрая скорость установки и небольшой размер установочника.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) или [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Для [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) точно есть модули для установи баз данных.

Answer (score 2):

Я воспользовался программой Smart Install Maker просто понятно и для тех кто не знает английский присутствует русский язык.